# position relative in logo is not working

Tags: html, css

I have created a design which is below

http://jsfiddle.net/g9TT7/1/

i want to put logo means below top and left side of the page

```
<a href="index.html"  style="margin-top:10px;position:relative!important;width:200px;display:block;" class="img1">
<img src="image/img_2.png" alt="logo" />
</a>
```

here i want to put business name in the center of the page and logo will be on the left side of the page. I have set position absolute in my logo but not working.
Please help me to do this.

Comment: Looks ok in the fiddle

Comment: yeah but i cant click on the logo

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you want something like this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9TT7/3/)

Add css float:left in your logo style and remove position absolute from business div.
You can also adjust position from top and left by playing with margin.

HTML:

```
<div class="b" style="text-align:center;">      

        <a href="index.html" class="img1">
                <img src="image/img_2.png" alt="logo" />
        </a>

        <div class="business_name" >
                            Business
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
.img1{
    margin-top:20px;
    width:200px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
.business_name {
    width: 78%;
    font-size: 43px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.b {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 78.5%;
    text-align: left;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0px;
    color: rgb(67, 161, 240);
}
.img1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 2px 0px 0px;
    width: 20%;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ADDTn/

```
<div class="header">
    <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="img.jpg" />
    </a>
    <h1>Bussiness</h1>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: yeah its working. Thanks. But i have to take business name in a div

Comment: @user2790769 If the business needs to be in the div, just move it down to the div.

Comment: @user2790769 just change h1 to div :) add class with text-align: center in css... http://jsfiddle.net/ADDTn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Assign the z-index value

```
<a href="index.html"  style="margin-top:10px;position:relative!important;width:200px;display:block; z-index: 1;" class="img1">
<img src="image/img_2.png" alt="logo" />
</a>
```

[see this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9TT7/2/)

Comment: i need only logo to be linked not business